# How to resolve IOException while renaming file using SFTP?

Tags: java, file, sftp

I am using **SFTPClient** to **download** and **upload files**. Here requirement is while downloading from remote server, needed to move the file in archive folder in the same server. 
I know that, we have option to rename using below one-: **

> SFTPClient.rename(filename,destinationPath)

**.
I have tried the same but i am getting following exception:
**code:**

```
try {
        sftp.lcd(details.get("LOCAL_DIR"));
        sftp.cd(details.get("REMOTE_DIR"));

        List<SftpFile> remoteFiles = sftp.ls();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < remoteFiles.size(); ++i) {
            String patternFile = remoteFiles.get(i).getFilename().toUpperCase();
        //  System.out.println(patternFile);
        //  System.out.println("Files Format"+patternFile+"***************"+patternFile.matches(details.get("DOWNLOAD_PATTERN")));
            if(remoteFiles.get(i).isFile() && patternFile.matches(details.get("DOWNLOAD_PATTERN"))) {
                String remoteFile = remoteFiles.get(i).getFilename();
                sftp.get(remoteFile);
                System.out.println("[SFTPOperations][downLoad] Downloaded: " + remoteFile);
                System.out.println("Remote File: " + remoteFile);
                System.out.println("Remote Archive Dir: " + details.get("REMOTE_ARCHIVE_DIR"));
                sftp.rename(remoteFiles.get(i).getFilename(), details.get("REMOTE_ARCHIVE_DIR"));
                System.out.println("[SFTPOperations][downLoad] Archived: " + remoteFile);
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("[SFTPOperations][downLoad] IOException occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("[SFTPOperations][downLoad] Failed to download from " + details.get("REMOTE_DIR"));
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        throw new SFTPException(e.getMessage());
    }
```

**Exception:**

> [Jun 04 10:57:58] [SFTPOperations][downLoad] IOException occurred:
>   Failure [Jun 04 10:57:58] [SFTPOperations][downLoad] Failed to
>   download from /home/cordys/CryptoTest/INGInput java.io.IOException:
>   Failure [Jun 04 10:57:58]     at
>   com.sshtools.j2ssh.sftp.SftpSubsystemClient.getOKRequestStatus(Unknown
>   Source) [Jun 04 10:57:58]     at
>   com.sshtools.j2ssh.sftp.SftpSubsystemClient.renameFile(Unknown Source)
>   [Jun 04 10:57:58]     at com.sshtools.j2ssh.SftpClient.rename(Unknown
>   Source) [Jun 04 10:57:58]     at
>   com.ing.sftp.SFTPOperations.downLoad(SFTPOperations.java:82) [Jun 04
>   10:57:58]     at
>   com.ing.schedular.INGCryptoSchedular.downloadEncFiles(INGCryptoSchedular.java:207)
>   [Jun 04 10:57:58]     at
>   com.ing.schedular.INGCryptoSchedular.download(INGCryptoSchedular.java:187)
>   [Jun 04 10:57:58]     at
>   com.ing.schedular.INGCryptoSchedular.schedule(INGCryptoSchedular.java:83)
>   [Jun 04 10:57:58]     at
>   com.ing.schedular.INGCryptoSchedular.main(INGCryptoSchedular.java:294)

Please suggest how to resolve the mentioned above.

Comment: Get the source and have a look at the code throwing the exception?

Comment: yeah i tried to open the source, it's showing like, "The jar file j2ssh-core-0.2.9.jar has no source attachment". After attached jar file in the class File Editor. Please suggest me.

Comment: You need to download the source separately and attach it.  Perhaps even unzip it manually first.